# What do Haskell (data) constructors construct?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, algebraic-data-types

Haskell enables one to construct algebraic data types using type constructors and data constructors.  For example,

```
data Circle = Circle Float Float Float
```

and we are told this data constructor (Circle on right) is a function that constructs a circle when give data, e.g. x, y, radius.

```
Circle :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Circle
```

My questions are:

1. What is actually constructed by this function, specifically?
2. Can we define the constructor function?

I've seen Smart Constructors but they just seem to be extra functions that eventually call the regular constructors.

Coming from an OO background, constructors, of course, have imperative specifications.  In Haskell, they seem to be system-defined.

Comment: to sum up the answers: 1. plain records of three Float values, tagged as "Circle"; 2. we just did, with the `data` declaration.

Answer (score 19):

In Haskell, without considering the underlying implementation, a data constructor creates a value, essentially by fiat. “ ‘Let there be a `Circle`’, said the programmer, and there was a `Circle`.” Asking what `Circle 1 2 3` creates is akin to asking what the literal `1` creates in Python or Java.

A nullary constructor is closer to what you usually think of as a literal. The `Boolean` type is *literally* defined as

```
data Boolean = True | False
```

where `True` and `False` are data constructors, not literals defined by Haskell grammar.

The data type is also the definition of the constructor; as there isn't really anything to a value beyond the constructor name and its arguments, simply stating it *is* the definition. You create a value of type `Circle` by calling the data constructor `Circle` with 3 arguments, and that's it.

A so-called "smart constructor" is just a function that calls a data constructor, with perhaps some other logic to restrict which instances can be created. For example, consider a simple wrapper around `Integer`:

```
newtype PosInteger = PosInt Integer
```

The constructor is `PosInt`; a smart constructor might look like

```
mkPosInt :: Integer -> PosInteger
mkPosInt n | n > 0 = PosInt n
           | otherwise = error "Argument must be positive"
```

With `mkPosInt`, there is no way to create a `PosInteger` value with a non-positive argument, because only positive arguments actually call the data constructor. A smart constructor makes the most sense when it, and not the data constructor, is exported by a module, so that a typical user cannot create arbitrary instances (because the data constructor does not exist outside the module).

Answer (score 13):

Good question.  As you know, given the definition:

```
data Foo = A | B Int
```

this defines a type with a (nullary) type constructor `Foo` and two data constructors, `A` and `B`.

Each of these data constructors, when fully applied (to no arguments in the case of `A` and to a single `Int` argument in the case of `B`) constructs a value of type `Foo`.  So, when I write:

```
a :: Foo
a = A

b :: Foo
b = B 10
```

the names `a` and `b` are bound to two values of type `Foo`.

**So, data constructors for type `Foo` construct values of type `Foo`.**

What are values of type `Foo`?  Well, first of all, they are different from values of any other type.  Second, they are wholly defined by their data constructors.  There is a distinct value of type `Foo`, different from all other values of `Foo`, for each combination of a data constructor with a set of distinct arguments passed to that data constructor.  That is, two values of type `Foo` are identical if and only if they were constructed with the same data constructor given identical sets of arguments.  ("Identical" here means something different from "equality", which may not necessarily be defined for a given type `Foo`, but let's not get into that.)

That's also what makes data constructors different from functions in Haskell.  If I have a function:

```
bar :: Int -> Bool
```

It's possible that `bar 1` and `bar 2` might be exactly the same value.  For example, if `bar` is defined by:

```
bar n = n > 0
```

then it's obvious that `bar 1` and `bar 2` (and `bar 3`) are identically `True`.  Whether the value of `bar` is the same for different values of its arguments will depend on the function definition.

In contrast, if `Bar` is a constructor:

```
data BarType = Bar Int
```

then it's never going to be the case that `Bar 1` and `Bar 2` are the same value.  By definition, they will be different values (of type `BarType`).

By the way, the idea that constructors are just a special kind of function is a common viewpoint.  I personally think this is inaccurate and causes confusion.  While it's true that constructors can often be used as if they are functions (specifically that they behave very much like functions when used in expressions), I don't think this view stands up under much scrutiny -- constructors are represented differently in the surface syntax of the language (with capitalized identifiers), can be used in contexts (like pattern matching) where functions cannot be used, are represented differently in compiled code, etc.

So, when you ask "can we define the constructor function", the answer is "no", because there is no constructor function.  Instead, a constructor like `A` or `B` or `Bar` or `Circle` is what it is -- something different from a function (that sometimes behaves like a function with some special additional properties) which is capable of constructing a value of whatever type the data constructor belongs to.

This makes Haskell constructors very different from OO constructors, but that's not surprising since Haskell values are very different from OO objects.  In an OO language, you can typically provide a constructor function that does some processing in building the object, so in Python you might write:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.value = n > 0
```

and then after:

```
bar1 = Bar(1)
bar2 = Bar(2)
```

we have two distinct objects `bar1` and `bar2` (which would satify `bar1 != bar2`) that have been configured with the same field values and are in some sense "equal".  This is sort of halfway between the situation above with `bar 1` and `bar 2` creating two identical values (namely `True`) and the situation with `Bar 1` and `Bar 2` creating two distinct values that, by definition, can't possibly be the "same" in any sense.

You can never have this situation with Haskell constructors.  Instead of thinking of a Haskell constructor as running some underlying function to "construct" an object which might involve some cool processing and deriving of field values, you should instead think of a Haskell constructor as a passive tag attached to a value (which may also contain zero or more other values, depending on the arity of the constructor).

So, in your example, `Circle 10 20 5` doesn't "construct" an object of type `Circle` by running some function.  It directly creates a tagged object that, in memory, will look something like:

```
<Circle tag>
<Float value 10>
<Float value 20>
<Float value 5>
```

(or you can at least pretend that's what it looks like in memory).

The closest you can come to OO constructors in Haskell is using smart constructors.  As you note, eventually a smart constructor just calls a regular constructor, because that's the only way to create a value of a given type.  No matter what kind of bizarre smart constructor you build to create a `Circle`, the value it constructs will need to look like:

```
<Circle tag>
<some Float value>
<another Float value>
<a final Float value>
```

which you'll need to construct with a plain old `Circle` constructor call.  There's nothing else the smart constructor could return that would still be a `Circle`.  That's just how Haskell works.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I guessed this was the case but could not find confirmation anywhere (easily).  I'm thinking there could perhaps be a better word to use than constructor (specifically for those coming from OO).  In fact, I think it may be easier to think of all data constructors as literals, just in a very big space that is too large to enumerate :-)  For example, Circle 1.0 2.0 3.0 as a literal?

Comment: Yes, that seems fairly accurate.  Of course, you can write `Circle (10/10) (1+1) (sqrt 9)` which looks less literal, but it's a literal in much the same sense a Javascript array or object literal or a Python tuple literal is a literal.

Comment: In an expression context, a constructor really *is* a function (or value). Ultimately, a non-nullary constructor is compiled to (inlined) code that allocates a heap object. What makes that so different from another function? In a pattern context, a constructor takes on an entirely different meaning to the compiler, of course.

Comment: Reasonable people can disagree, but I stand by my claim that a constructor isn't a function, and calling it one (which includes claiming it really is a function in one context but not another) trivializes the differences and -- as evidenced by this question -- mostly causes confusion.

Comment: I've updated my answer, though, to avoid claiming that the "constructor as function" view is a "mistake".

Comment: ... and the closest we can come to Haskell constructors in OO -- say, C++ -- is with compound data types, aka records, aka structs: in pseudocode `struct {float x,y,r} circle; main(){ struct circle c1; /* here c1 is created with its fields still _unassigned_ */ c1.x = 0.0; /* etc. */ }`. There's no "unassigned" in Haskell, and so `c1 = Circle 0.0 1.0 2.0` creates it in one step. For sum types, we add tagged unions to the above. SICP calls this "tagged lists"; EOPL has `variant-case` to handle these; etc.

Answer (score 13):

I’m going to answer this in a somewhat roundabout way, with an example that I hope illustrates my point, which is that Haskell *decouples* several distinct ideas that are coupled in OOP under the concept of a “class”. Understanding this will help you translate your experience from OOP into Haskell with less difficulty. The example in OOP pseudocode:

```
class Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Person(int id, String name) {
        if (id == 0)
            throw new InvalidIdException();
        if (name == "")
            throw new InvalidNameException();

        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() { return this.id; }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

}
```

In Haskell:

```
module Person
  ( Person
  , mkPerson
  , getId
  , getName
  , setName
  ) where

data Person = Person
  { personId :: Int
  , personName :: String
  }

mkPerson :: Int -> String -> Either String Person
mkPerson id name
  | id == 0 = Left "invalid id"
  | name == "" = Left "invalid name"
  | otherwise = Right (Person id name)

getId :: Person -> Int
getId = personId

getName :: Person -> String
getName = personName

setName :: String -> Person -> Either String Person
setName name person = mkPerson (personId person) name
```

Notice:

- The `Person` class has been translated to a *module* which happens to export a data type by the same name—*types* (for domain representation and invariants) are decoupled from *modules* (for namespacing and code organisation).
- The fields `id` and `name`, which are specified as `private` in the `class` definition, are translated to ordinary (public) fields on the `data` definition, since in Haskell they’re made private by omitting them from the export list of the `Person` module—*definitions* and *visibility* are decoupled.
- The constructor has been translated into two parts: one (the `Person` data constructor) that simply initialises the fields, and another (`mkPerson`) that performs validation—*allocation & initialisation* and *validation* are decoupled. Since the `Person` type is exported, but its constructor is not, this is the only way for clients to construct a `Person`—it’s an “abstract data type”.
- The public interface has been translated to functions that *are* exported by the `Person` module, and the `setName` function that previously *mutated* the `Person` object has become a function that returns a new instance of the `Person` data type that happens to share the old ID. **The OOP code has a bug**: it should include a check in `setName` for the `name != ""` invariant; the Haskell code can avoid this by using the `mkPerson` smart constructor to ensure that all `Person` values are valid by construction. So *state transitions* and *validation* are also decoupled—you only need to check invariants when constructing a value, because it can’t change thereafter.

So as for your actual questions:

> 1. What is actually constructed by this function, specifically?

A constructor of a data type allocates space for the tag and fields of a value, sets the tag to which constructor was used to create the value, and initialises the fields to the arguments of the constructor. You can’t override it because the process is completely mechanical and there’s no reason (in normal safe code) to do so. It’s an internal detail of the language and runtime.

> 2. Can we define the constructor function?

No—if you want to perform additional validation to enforce invariants, you should use a “smart constructor” function which calls the lower-level data constructor. Because Haskell values are immutable by default, values can be made *correct by construction*; that is, when you don’t have mutation, you don’t need to enforce that all state *transitions* are correct, only that all states *themselves* are constructed correctly. And often you can arrange your types so that smart constructors aren’t even necessary.

The only thing you can change about the generated data constructor “function” is making its type signature *more restrictive* using GADTs, to help enforce more invariants at compile-time. And as a side note, GADTs also let you do *existential quantification*, which lets you carry around encapsulated/type-erased information at runtime, *exactly* like an OOP vtable—so this is another thing that’s decoupled in Haskell but coupled in typical OOP languages.

Long story short (too late), you can do all the same things, you just arrange them differently, because Haskell provides the various features of OOP classes under separate orthogonal language features.

Comment: SO is badly broken, is too much time-dependent. your great answer only got a small number of views! (and more than one of those are from me.) :[  The more answers we add, the more less discoverable in the future they become. And there's no mechanism for the "community" to assign weight/importance to entries so that the system would propagate them more. if our goal is a set of canonical Q&A entries -- much less the actual knowledge discovery and maintenance system -- then SO is definitely **not it**. (IMO the root cause is the "one man one vote" attitude.) cf. meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366192 :)

Comment: also, we need a classification of entries for their target audience level -- novice, beginner .. expert (even better, paragraphs (auto-)collapsible dependent on the reader's level!). but SO is too rigid, and meta is affected by different communities with diff't attitudes, -- no hope for any meaningful change. looking back, if all these efforts were spent on the long abandoned haskellwiki / haskell wikibook(s), maybe the *Haskell* community overall would've been the better for it. (some kind of reputation tracking system probably would need to have been added, for that to have happened). alas.

Comment: @WillNess: Thanks, and yeah, I feel it—sometimes I’ll even refrain from upvoting a question for a while after answering it so that my answer gets another round of views when I bump the question by upvoting it. I suppose I (or you or anybody) could share a question/answer elsewhere as well, if it seems useful or interesting enough to put in front of a wider audience such as /r/haskell.

Comment: Didn't know mere upvoting bumps the question. Where does it do that?  I usually open a tag-based search page, and choose either "newest" or "active". I don't think it's showing up there.

Comment: @WillNess: I think voting counts as “activity”—might be mistaken. I usually browse [questions/tagged/haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) by “newest” though when trawling for questions.